# Rails validation error with .find_or_initialize_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

In my rails application I have a class called `PushToken`:

```
class PushToken < ApplicationRecord                                             
  validates :user, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }                        
  validates :token, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: true }                        
  validates :user, :token, presence: true
end
```

and my controller looks like this:

```
class PushTokensController < ApiController                                    
  def create                                                                          
    # current_user is a string (id)                    
    PushToken.find_or_initialize_by(user: current_user)                    
             .update!(create_params)                                          
                                                                                    

    # ... rest of the controller action
  end

  private

  def create_params
    params.permit(:token)
  end
end
```

From my perspective this should either create a new `PushToken` or update the `token` attribute of an existing one.

Now in production I am receiving this error at the `update!` line:

```
Validation failed: User has already been taken, Token has already been taken
```

And I don't understand how this happens. If `user` and `token` are already taken then it should update the existing record and not try to create a new one?

Does anyone know how this happens?

Comment: Check how many records do you in the database for that user. It could be that there are more than one. Do you have unique indices at the database layer? [Validating uniqueness without such an index can sometime lead to duplicate entries](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations).

Comment: @AbM That's a bingo! No unique indices - multiple records - errors on saving. Thank you! If you want ,you can copy your comment as an answer and I will mark it as solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check how many records you have in the database for that user. It could be that there are more than one. Do you have unique indices at the database layer? [Validating uniqueness without such an index can sometime lead to duplicate entries](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations).

There is also another potential reason this could fail - I don't know your implementation of `current_user`. You have:

```
validates :user, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

But the `find_or_initialize_by` is case sensitive. So consider this scenario:

For the first request, `current_user` is `test`. So you create a PushToken (call it `token1`) with `test` as the `user` attribute

For the second request, `current_user` is `TEST`. This in theory should match to `token1` since `user` is not case sensitive. But the `find_or_initialize_by` will not find an existing record and therefore initialize a new record. You will then run into the same validation issue when calling `update!`

One way to get around this is to always `downcase` the `user` attribute and make the uniqueness case sensitive